# Transform a object into a new object object.assign

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 objects:

```
 const refer = [
  { key: 'A.ABC', value: 'ABC', display: 'ABC' },
  { key: 'A.PQR', value: 'INFOPQR', display: 'PQR' },
  { key: 'Q', value: 'Q', display: 'Q'},
 ]

 const mapObj = [
   {id: "A.ABC", name: "other value"},
   {id: "A.PQR", name: "some values"},
 ]
```

I want to return a new object by applying a transform layer to mapObject that is basically like:

```
  [
   {id: "A.ABC", name: "other value"},
   {id: "INFOPQR", name: "some values"},
  ]
```

notice that the value from refer object should be the id in mapObj only if the key of refer matches to id of mapobj.

```
const transform = refer => {
  refer.map(r => {
    const f = mapObj.filter(d => d.id === r.id);

  });
}
```

I have the above so far. How do I use Object.assign to actually transform.

Comment: Why does `A.PQR` get transformed but `A.ABC` does not? It's pretty unclear what you want to do.

Comment: And none of this has anything to do with spread syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `map()` and `find()` methods, and if `key` matches `id` from object in other array you can use `Object.assign()` to return new object else return current object.

```js
 const refer = [
  { key: 'A.ABC', value: 'ABC', display: 'ABC' },
  { key: 'A.PQR', value: 'INFOPQR', display: 'PQR' },
  { key: 'Q', value: 'Q', display: 'Q'},
 ]

 const mapObj = [
   {id: "A.ABC", name: "other value"},
   {id: "A.PQR", name: "some values"},
 ]
const result = mapObj.map(o => {
  const ref = refer.find(e => e.key == o.id)
  return !ref ? o : Object.assign({}, o, {id: ref.value})
})

console.log(result)
```